# How can I diagnose what happened after a system was exposed to infection?

Tags: network, virus, forensics

A system was connected to an already infected (or not secure) network and was used for few hours for normal use before the infection or hacking was detected. What things or steps should be taken to verify system and network security and integrity?

Comment: The simple answer is "anything" - so I have edited your question a wee bit. What steps should be taken could be a useful headline question - we have a range of forensics questions here, on how to track malicious actions (automated or manually via C&C)

Comment: It depends on whether you want to analyze what happened to the system for research reasons (in which case it is forensics but frankly if you do not know the steps you mention you will not get much from a forensics session) or to check if the system is compromised and how -- in which case, if you have a doubt, you are better off reinstalling. You will likely spend the same time as in checking but at least you will know that you are clean.